# Is the support of an Artinian module finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $R$ is an Artinian ring then it has finite maximal ideals.
If $M$ is an $R$-module Artinian. ($R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring). Then, is $Supp(M)$ finite?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered here:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71862/is-the-support-of-an-artinian-module-finite